# How is the principle root defined?

Tags: complex-numbers, radicals

I always thought that the principle root of $n$ was defined as the only positive real solution for $n$. But what is defined as the principal root for numbers with no positive real $n$th roots? An example would be $\sqrt[3]{-1}$. Wolfram Alpha says its principle root is $\frac{1+i*\sqrt[2]{3}}{2}$, but why not its conjugate? And if it's defined as the root $a$ that fits the criteria Rez(a)>0, what about numbers that have more than one root that fit this criteria? Thanks in advance :]

Comment: https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/principal_root#:~:text=principal%20root%20(plural%20principal%20roots,equality%20of%20the%20real%20parts. Clearly if the real parts are equal the imaginary ones have to be conjugate

Comment: The principle root is the one whose polar form $re^{i\theta}$ has the smallest $\theta \ge 0$.